# Plotting time series price range date from the recent with error value does not match datetime frame

Tags: plot

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[15, 7])
plt.suptitle('Bitcoin exchanges, Weighted_Price USD', fontsize=22)

plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(Bitcoin.Weighted_Price, '-', label='By Days')
plt.legend()
```

[matplotlib error: Price value inverse to the date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcY0w.png)

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please state your problem in more detail. I don't see the problem with your graph.

Comment: images made visible

Comment: the year started 2009 to 2019 with the inception listed price from just above $0 (around $6), year showing correctly 2010-2019 on X-axis however, the Y-axis showing like a mirror-inverse image with inception price at right and ending-price at left side of the Plot chart. The csv table lists data as top-down ts value (recent date on top), even i stated date range to be started 13-09-2009 ends 03-09-2019, the chart Y-value does not right. Thank you for your help. Weina

Comment: rng = pd.DataFrame(Bitcoin, columns = ['Date'])
rng['Date'] = pd.date_range('13/09/2009',periods = 2911, freq='d')
rng['Date']

Comment: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
sns.lineplot(x=rng['Date'], 
             y=Bitcoin.Weighted_Price,
             color='r',
             ax=ax) 
ax.legend(['Bitcoin Weighted Price', 'USD'], facecolor='w')
plt.show()

Comment: I tried above way to re-plot, however, the colab jupyter notebook showing the same image by reading the Y-value straight from the data csv table (recent date on top which is showing at the left-side of chart) whereas the X-axis correctly picking up year 2010-2019 (left-to-right)